# Dynamically type an object based on an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
type paramType = {type: string, value: string | number }

const PROFILE: Record<string, paramType> = {
  color: { type: 'string', value: 'red' },
  height: { type: 'number', value: 180 },
  weight: { type: 'number', value: 70 },
}

const constructObj = (selectedFields: string[]) => {
  return selectedFields.reduce((accum, cur) => {
            return { ...accum, [cur]: PROFILE[cur] };
        }, {} as Record<typeof selectedFields[number], paramType>);
}

const result = constructObj(['color']); // { color: {type: 'string', value: 'red' } }
// 1. result.color // Not throwing error, great
// 2. result.xxx // Not throwing error, Not good
```

`constructObj` is a function that will dynamically return an object with keys defined in `selectedFields`. I'm facing an issue where `result.xxx` is not throwing error?

Comment: `constructObj` would need to be generic: `<T extends readonly string[]>(selectedFields: T)`, and you'd need to pass `constructObj(['color'] as const)`, or `['color']` will be inferred as `string[]`, which is too wide.

Comment: Note i am somewhat in a hurry, so i didn't consider potential alternatives, and can't write an answer right now, so if someone else wants to go into more detail, go ahead ;)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different solution from what @ASDFGerte suggested. With this you don't need the `as const` when calling the array. Personally, think it looks cleaner.

```js
type paramType = { type: string; value: string | number };

const PROFILE: Record<string, paramType> = {
  color: { type: "string", value: "red" },
  height: { type: "number", value: 180 },
  weight: { type: "number", value: 70 },
};

const constructObj = <T extends string>(
  selectedFields: T[]
): Record<T, paramType> => {
  return selectedFields.reduce((accum, cur) => {
    return { ...accum, [cur]: PROFILE[cur] };
  }, {} as Record<typeof selectedFields[number], paramType>);
};

const result = constructObj(["color"]); // { color: {type: 'string', value: 'red' } }
result.color; // Not throwing error, great
result.xxx; // Throwing error now
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QqsQxSUlUgtVuAqIDPr9ADk5DbgGl4HImjYtvBs-A6FR4rBgJI49bUdsa8moGmM1mc3nRIW6A2oFQ5HIzJIgA)

Comment: One issue here is that `value` is always `string | number`..

Answer (score 0):

Addressing @Keith's comment on @nullptr's answer, we can instead use this magic to infer the complete type of `selectedFields` without `as const` *and* without the drawback that the result's `value` is not `string | number`.

However you do have to sacrifice a *little* inside the body of the function, but hey, a little sacrifice for great typings sounds great to me.

The core of this solution is this interesting definition:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });
```

Essentially it's a bunch of "tests" to get TypeScript inferring what `T` is.

Here is my definition of `constructObj`:

```
const constructObj = <T>(selectedFields: Narrow<T>): T extends string[] ? {
  [K in T[number]]: K extends keyof typeof PROFILE_TYPE ? typeof PROFILE_TYPE[K] : never;
} : never => {
  return (selectedFields as string[]).reduce((accum, cur) => {
    return { ...accum, [cur]: PROFILE[cur] };
  }, {} as ReturnType<typeof constructObj<T>>);
}
```

We use `Narrow` to narrow down `T`. That means when we call it like this:

```
constructObj(["color"]);
```

`T` will be `["color"]`, not `string[]`! Of course once we have the tuple, we can iterate over the elements with `K in T[number]`, and that's our result done.

You'll notice that there is `PROFILE_TYPE` now instead of `PROFILE`. What's that?

I changed `PROFILE` to this:

```
const PROFILE_TYPE = {
  color: { type: 'string', value: 'red' },
  height: { type: 'number', value: 180 },
  weight: { type: 'number', value: 70 },
};

const PROFILE = PROFILE_TYPE as Record<string, paramType>;
```

So you'll have your original `PROFILE`, *but* you also have the original that you can use for typings. The best of both worlds.

[And this works amazingly.](https://tsplay.dev/wXjLQm)

---

Still confused about `Narrow`?

The way I have used it above is *essentially equivalent* to the following:

```
const constructObj = <T>(selectedFields: [T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Extract<T[K], string> }): T extends string[] ? {
```

Yeah I don't think it's nice to read or maintain either.
But again, what it does, is it tests `T` is an empty array with `[T] extends [[]]`, then if it isn't, it "loops" over the tuple (because looping over it makes TypeScript infer it as a tuple for some reason) and then uses `Extract<T[K], string>` to *further* get TypeScript to infer each individual string as a literal.