# Create a function with a specific mapped type as return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I am trying to create a method that iterates over an object and replaces every key-value pair where the value extends `{ _id: Types.ObjectId }` with a modified key and maps the value to the string representation of `_id`. So, for example

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "image": {
    "_id": "63162902546ac59fb830ccae",
    "url": "https://..."
  }
}
```

would be transformed to

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "imageId": "63162902546ac59fb830ccae"
}
```

Additionally, it should be possible to specify keys which don't get modified. So, if I'd pass `image` in the example above, the object would remain unchanged.

So far, I have created a mapped type that looks as follows

```
type TransformedResponse<T, R extends keyof T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends R
    ? K
    : T[K] extends { _id: Types.ObjectId }
    ? `${string & K}Id`
    : K]: K extends R
    ? T[K]
    : T[K] extends { _id: Types.ObjectId }
    ? string
    : T[K];
}
```

and seems to produce the expected types:

```
interface Example {
  name: string;
  image: {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    url: string;
  };
}
type T1 = TransformedResponse<Example, 'name'>; // { name: string; imageId: string; }
type T2 = TransformedResponse<Example, 'image'>; // { name: string; image: { _id: Types.ObjectId; url: string; } }
```

The function that performs the actual transformation looks as follows

```
export function ResponseTransformer<T>(
  obj: T,
  relations: (keyof T)[]
): TransformedResponse<T, keyof T> {
  const transformedObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] && obj[key]._id && !relations.includes(key as keyof T)) {
      transformedObj[`${key}Id`] = obj[key].toString();
    } else {
      transformedObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return transformedObj as TransformedResponse<T, keyof T>;
}
```

A call of this function, such as

```
const example = {
  name: 'test',
  image: {
    _id: '63162902546ac59fb830ccae',
    url: 'test',
  },
};
const t1 = ResponseTransformer(example, ['name']);
```

does not produce the expected type `T1` (see above) but actually a generic response (`TransformedResponse<T, keyof T>`). In the places where I call the function, the exact type `T1` is required as the return type, which causes type checking to fail.

How can I make the function return the specific type?

Additionally: How can I make the type's generic argument `R` optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `relations` must be its own generic type. Otherwise it is just `keyof T` but not the actually values you passed to the function.

```
export function ResponseTransformer<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  relations: K[]
): Expand<TransformedResponse<T, K>> {
  return {} as any
}

type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

TypeScript has some problems displaying the correct return type. But adding [`Expand`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683652/8613630) fixes this.

Also, don't forget to actually pass an `ObjectId` to the function and not a `string`.

```
const example = {
  name: 'test',
  image: {
    _id: '63162902546ac59fb830ccae' as unknown as Types.ObjectId,
    url: 'test',
  },
};
const t1 = ResponseTransformer(example, ['name']); 
// const t1: {
//     name: string;
//     imageId: string;
// }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgN4ICoE8IFMDOCC%20CAZjFGAgERhQB2A5lFDlhcMHJlmjAIY05FYYLABMASrmj8sAHlQAaBGIRYAHnCw0ReANZZ0UImgB8CALzJgCBAG0A0ghA0Eeg0dQIeeB2o1a8YlbWCAD8CHZB1gBcaPYAuirqmtrICAD6ICIxGNg4AHQA8gBGAFZYAMZwAJIiBJGhCAAGACRIOHAwTnQIAGTh%20DWN9TF2cSOJfimBwQ2o8cOxoxPJeCgZWWic%20cVllTV1M2HtnfQLc6MA3MD4bE4aMEQ85VwAoqo8kAA2XEhBNB9YGLHLpXazgHh0QGWGbrbJbQqlCrVESg4IAVxgnyBHRBQXwVxuHGwaAAjOZuHwBEJRBIcFJmDI3h8IN9FAByf7CNnGC4IAD0fNSnKhwPovPBkJq2JOdF5hM4aAATOTULx%20IIYMJxJJaAymV8sOyJVhubyBUKAdKQY4wBCoWtMnDcgjdsjeRisQhRbKCHV2Aq3hA%20CI5KYLB5fCtHDQiFgYAgCg0UPZoy59IYE2ME-FfTEaFgAG5xq7ANTQeDENE0SogWhKHXSVWUjXCGByRQ%20JL%20NNuEwACiCUFK2XkQRgWE%20PDgtf4IxscWAAEoYoHg3I1VTNTSGwyFOFjKZftZx3AMc4kIQvJ4aOhrmxyrrEGpmd9yUeEMKYmyNO02aOwbakIxO%201iwggbIAGwAMwkhBioAJwAAyKgArAALBBTwofBRBFAAHFBiHlOUPAmp4eBVjoNBQAA7s4V45LgLpIjU-7opiX4-nAf54qO%20LAA%20-CIHAZIWLS9JYE26rUjAfbPgaig2ByAJsnEi68sA5qCe0CAicBmmCjMn5ejiYoGTMNp2lKJkylc5r4EAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was helpful! Do you also have any advice on how to make `relations` optional?

Comment: @BenjaminFrost - Here take a look: https://tsplay.dev/mqkgJw. You can put `never` as the default type for the generic

Answer (score 0):

Narrow the type of `relations`, then proceed to use the inferred tuple in the return type like this:

```
export function ResponseTransformer<T, R>(
  obj: T,
  relations: [R] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof R]: Extract<R[K], keyof T> }
): TransformedResponse<T, R extends (keyof T)[] ? R[number] : keyof T> {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wORVRW)

---

A little more detail on the narrowing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73612791/18244921).